# How do you set a condition based on the month of the 'created_at' field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

controller code that doesn't work:

```
@mailings = Mailing.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at.month = ?", m])
```

Error msg:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'created_at.month' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `mailings` WHERE (created_at.month = 10)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@mailings = Mailing.find(:all, :conditions => ["MONTH(created_at) = ?", m])
```

Assuming you're using MySQL you can find more in the Docs: [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `:conditions` argument of `find` is interpolated directly into the resulting SQL. Thus, you can use SQL commands.

You could try the following if you're using MySQL:

```
@mailings = Mailing.find(:all, :conditions => ["MONTH(created_at) = ?", m])
```

Or this, for SQLite:

```
@mailings = Mailing.find(:all, :conditions => ["strftime('%m', created_at) = ?", m])
```